# python logger, disable log for some modules

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to disable logs for some modules in my project? I have this log_config.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=stream_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-4s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[logger_modulename]
handlers=null_handler
propagate=0
qualname=modulename
level=NOTSET

[handler_null_handler]
class=NullHandler
level=NOTSET
```

Do not forget to add `null_handler` and `modulename` under `handler` and `loggers` sections.